# sql profiler causes 'scan with NOLOCK due to data movement'

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, profiler, sql-server-profiler

I have a procedure that fills up a bunch of regular and temp tables with millions of records and takes hours to complete.  Its no problem when I run it alone.

However, I've been trying to improve performance and am trying a SQL Profiler tuning trace.  Now the procedure bombs every time with :

> Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.

If I turn off SQL Profiler it works again.  My system is SQL R2 64 SP2 on a Dell Precision T5400 quad Xeon, 8gb RAM and plenty of storage capacity (3tb) on W2k8 Server 64 (latest sp).

Comment: Also, the server is isolated.  No other DB is running and the only activity is this procedure.  There are no outside connections--just this proc.

Comment: SQL Profiler changes timing significantly and may expose a race condition which you have *anyway*. The exception you see is to be expected if you use NOLOCK in the procedure. Try using `sp_trace_xxx` server side tracing instead of SQL Profiler. Very few perf problems require SQL Profiler anyway, there are far better tools in the DMVs/wait_stats.

Comment: I don't use NOLOCK in the procedures.  Does that change your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to this query was to reduce the complexity of the query.  It was inserting millions of records in one big load.  I broke it into several smaller loads and this error went away.